# SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException cause Spring Transaction Rollback

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

Spring 4.1.4
Hibernate 4.2.0
JDK 1.8

My context: I have a Controller calling --> Service --> calling Dao
The business funcionality is to delete ( in 1 to many DB relation) some child ,but not all child .
Then ,after deleting some child I try to delete the Parent and offcourse I got java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

But the question is why transaction is market for Rollback ? ( in other words why I don't got the deletion of some child ?)

SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException is a checked exception and stating Spring documentation the behaviour would be the same of EJB : [Note that by default, rollback happens for runtime, unchecked exceptions only. The checked exception does not trigger a rollback of the transaction.](https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring)

I need to remove some child anf trying to remove the parent if possible, if not I need to commit the transaction maintaining the parent and remaining of childs
Note I tried also to specify in Service and Dao methods the Spring Annotation

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
```

To request explicitly the behaviour expected , but not even like this work for me

Controller code method:

```
public void delete() {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Data deleted.","");
    
    try{
        memoTemplateService.delete(memoTemplate);
        memoTemplates.remove(memoTemplate);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        msg=new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "A","B");
    }
    reset();

    
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

Service method :

```
@Override
@Transactional(noRollbackFor =  {SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class,DBConstraintException.class})
public void delete(MemoTemplate memoTemplate)throws BusinessException {
    // deleting some ,not all , child 
    phaseAndMemoGenerator.deleteMemosForVisibleTimeHorizon(memoTemplate);
    try{// some times Template cannot be deleted
        memoTemplateDao.delete(memoTemplate);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        throw new DBConstraintException("Partial Delete", "Template cannot be deleted, Memo in the past are present");
    }
}
```

Dao

```
@Repository(value = "memoTemplateDao")
public class MemoTemplateDaoImpl extends GenericJpaDaoImpl<MemoTemplate,  Long> implements MemoTemplateDao {

@Override
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
public void delete(MemoTemplate t) {
    super.delete(t);
    em.flush();
}
}
```

Just an Update : it's incredible but I can't catch neither doing the catch in Dao method ,debugger go in catch block but before this still a java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException is fired , incredible !

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class,PersistenceException.class})
public void tryToDelete(MemoTemplate t)throws Exception {
    super.delete(t);
    try{
        em.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        throw new Exception("ddddd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If  there are constraints defined in DB, you won't be able to bypass them by committing without rollback.

Comment: The situation is :relation 1 to many as A 1-->N B then I need to delete some record of child B based to some logic . As I don't know in advance how many record B will be deleted ,I will try to delete also the parent A (in case all child has removed) ; if the parent delete fail I want transation is committed as I retain the work about deleted child . SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException is thown at DAO and PersistentException is returned to SERVICE . Now the first Exception wouldn't rollback transaction,it is CHECKED EXCEPTION .The second is UNcheched but I put the noRollbackFor